# Webservices for Time display in ASP.net

Tags: web-services, datetime

I need to display the time information (IST,GMT,EST) times in my ASP.net web application. Is there any webervices providing these datas. It should be free.

Answer (score 0):

.NET BCL has pretty much everything you'd need. `DateTime` and `TimeZone` classes are your friends.